# How do fields exist in higher dimensions appear in the $D=4$ universe?

Tags: field-theory, string-theory, spacetime-dimensions

I'm studying a five-dimensional model with a spacetime background metric:

$
ds^2= e^{2\sigma} g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + dy^2,
$

Where $\sigma$ is called a dilaton field , $\mu,\nu=0, 1, 2,3$, and $y$ is the fifth extra dimension.

My question how this field which exists in the fifth dimension will be seen in the 4-dimentional universe? In other worlds, how $\sigma$ appears in the metric of the effective theory?

According to my solutions $ \sigma \propto y $ and it's mentioned in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221)  after equ (13) that the size of the extra dimension becomes in the 4D universe a vacuum expectation value for a new field called modulus field. So is this a general case?

Do the extra dimensions fields which are proportional to the extra dimension size raise new fields in our universe? And definitely , these fields will be different than gravitons